# I have a completionHandler for my database query, but now what?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I managed to create a database handler class that has a function to retrieve user data from firestore:

```
    func getArtistProfileCardData(artistName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){
        
        let usersRef = db.collection("users")
        usersRef.whereField("artistName", isEqualTo: artistName)
            .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                                do {
                                    let userData = try document.data(as: UserModel.self)
                                    completionHandler(userData)
                                    // printing retData.artistName gives me correct output.
                                } catch _ {
                                    print("Error getting document from querySnapshot.")
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
        }
```

I recently learned how to use completion handlers to return this data out of the DBHandler method. But, how do I go about using it for my SwiftUI views? The data is still inside a closure now like this:

```
struct ArtistProfileCard: View {
    @State var user: UserModel
    
    let dbhandler = DBHandler() 
    dbhandler.getArtistProfileCardData(artistName: "something") { userData in
        // stuff to do with userDAta
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Spacer()
            Text(user.artistName ?? "??")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .textCase(.uppercase)
            Text(user.occupation)
            Text("\(user.followers) Followers")
        }

// and the code continues like for any typical UI view...
```

and I don't know how to extract it out to put it in my View. Am I going about handling my database incorrectly? Should I completely change the approach to DB management in my App?

Here are some errors thrown when I try and run the code as above

[image: Some errors]

Comment: `self.user = userData`?

Comment: @Larme The thing is it doesn't even let me run the query method in the struct. It throws me various errors. I'll add them to my question above.

Comment: This is *UIKit-ish* code. Load the data in `.onAppear` or in a view model. And a `@State` property must be initialized. And even in UIKit you cannot run arbitrary code on the top level of a struct or class.

Comment: @vadian Do you have some good resources and/or links to understand how to do so? Specifically loading data into a view model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is SwiftUI. You don't need a completion handler.

Declare `DBHandler` as class conforming to `ObservableObject` and `userData` as `@Published` property.

Side note: `userData` should be non-optional by adding a static property to `UserModel` with example data. And you should also handle the error

```
class DBHandler : ObservableObject {

    @Published var userData: UserModel?
    // better: @Published var userData = UserModel.example

    init() {
       getArtistProfileCardData(artistName: "something")
    }

    func getArtistProfileCardData(artistName: String){
        
        let usersRef = db.collection("users")
        usersRef.whereField("artistName", isEqualTo: artistName)
            .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                                do {
                                    let userData = try document.data(as: UserModel.self)
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.userData = userData
                                    }
                                    
                                } catch {
                                    print("Error getting document from querySnapshot.", error)
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
        }

}
```

And in the view create an instance of `DBHandler` as @StateObject

```
struct ArtistProfileCard: View {
    @StateObject var dbhandler = DBHandler() 
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if let user = dbhandler.userData {
                Spacer()
                Text(user.artistName ?? "??")
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
                    .textCase(.uppercase)
                Text(user.occupation)
                Text("\(user.followers) Followers")
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all this information! Are there further readings and resources you can perhaps direct me to in regards to backend programming for SwiftUI? I'm more than willing to learn about it all!

Comment: A good source are the WWDC videos and [100 days of SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/201/start-the-100-days-of-swiftui) on hackingwithswift.com